# Discord.py rewrite 'Context' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.py

Last month I hosted a Discord.py (async version) bot on heroku and it worked perfect, this month I updated my bot from async to rewrite and it doesn't really work.

On my `requirements.txt` file I have put the `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py[voice]` but it doesn't work.

I always get this error:

```
2019-01-25T08:30:23.592293+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-01-25T08:30:23.592356+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
2019-01-25T08:30:23.592358+00:00 app[worker.1]: yield from command.invoke(ctx)
2019-01-25T08:30:23.592363+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in invoke
2019-01-25T08:30:23.592365+00:00 app[worker.1]: yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
2019-01-25T08:30:23.592395+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 54, in wrapped
2019-01-25T08:30:23.592397+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
2019-01-25T08:30:23.592435+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Script:

```py
print("Loading Script")
print("Loading Libs")

import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

print("Loading Bot")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')



@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Online!")

@bot.command()
async def rps(ctx):
    rpsa = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    rpsr = random.choice(rpsa)
    await ctx.send(rpsr)

bot.run(Token)
```

Comment: Could you add your requirements file to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have the right version installed? Just having it in your requirements file doesn't guarantee that you are using the right one. Check what you have installed with `pip freeze` and then uninstall if necessary the old async version.

Answer (score 0):

That type of error only occurs when you have the [async version](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) of `discord.py` installed and are using [rewrite](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/rewrite) features

Double check what your `requirements.txt` file is called (you've named it `requirement.txt` in the question) and check that it doesn't still contain `discord==0.0.2` or
`discord.py==0.16.12`

Comment: @ItsBenny_ make sure you don't have *both* installed. It's entirely likely that you installed `rewrite` without removing the `async` version as well, which would lead to something like this happening.